# Itext sharp 5.5.13 random errors like "The page 929 was requested but the document has only 928 pages."

Tags: itext

maybe one of you, had the same problem and could help me. We have got random errors during merge documents from code below:

```csharp
public static byte[] MergePdfFiles(List<byte[]> pdfFiles, object lockObject)
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document())
            {
                //you also see here that I did not put PdfSmartCopy into a using block. This is because the Document implicitly closes the PdfSmartCopy when it is disposed
                PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms) {CloseStream = false};
                doc.Open();

                //Loop through each byte array
                foreach (var pdfByte in pdfFiles)
                {
                    using (PdfReader pReader = new PdfReader(pdfByte))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                        {
                            PdfImportedPage pdfMerger = copy.GetImportedPage(pReader, i + 1);
                            copy.AddPage(pdfMerger);
                        }

                        copy.FreeReader(pReader);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Return just before disposing
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This errors occured during close document:

```
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()     
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy.Close()     
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()     
   at iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()     
   at iTextSharp.text.Document.Dispose()     
   at PdfTools.PdfHelperTools.MergePdfFiles(List`1 pdfFiles, Object lockObject) in C:\src\businessLogic-lib\PdfTools\PdfHelperTools.cs:line 154     
   at Lawsuit.LettersWithAttachments.LettersWithAttachmentsPrint.MakeControlPrint(Int32 controlPrintId) in C:\src\businessLogic-lib\Lawsuit.LettersWithAttachments\LettersWithAttachmentsPrint.cs:line 611     
   at Api.BusinessLayer.Manager.AttachmentManager.MakeControlPrint(Int32 controlPrintId) in C:\src\mService-RestService\Api.BusinessLayer\Manager\AttachmentManager.cs:line 94     
   at Services.Api.Controllers.LawsuitLegalController.PrintAttachmentLegalControlPrint(Int32 controlPrintId) in C:\src\LegalService-RestService\LegalService\Controllers\LawsuitLegalController.cs:line 213     
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()  
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Errors such as:

- The page 929 was requested but the document has only 928 pages.
- The page 693 was requested but the document has only 692 pages.
- The page 1090 was requested but the document has only 1089 pages.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: stack trace added

Comment: Please enclose the contents of the inner `using` block by `try ... catch (Exception)` and check whether there actually an exception is thrown that in your case causes another exception when leaving the `using (Document)` block.

Comment: I did as you wanted, this error is ocurred only after leaving the using document statement